# Drop rows if column is outside of variable defined range - R

Tags: r

I want to remove rows that have a similar 'y' value - that is if y is within +/- 100 of another value.

```
input = data.frame(x=c(100,200,100,300,200,100,200), y=c(800,850,900,100,901,701,699))
```

Input:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 800 |
| 200 | 850 |
| 100 | 900 |
| 300 | 100 |
| 100 | 701 |
| 200 | 699 |

Output:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 800 |
| 300 | 100 |
| 200 | 901 |
| 200 | 699 |

I can't quite workout how to do this in R, as I'm either deleting or leaving in values I don't want.

I think I might need to structure it as a set of pairwise comparisons. I'd sort by Y, then compare row 2 to row 1 and dropping, and if row 2 is outside of the range, treat that as my new comparison value and continue down the list.

But I don't know how to structure that - and I might be completely wrong, so open to suggestions!

Comment: Can you explain the logic ? which rows have to be filtered depending on which value?

Comment: Does x come into effect in this calculation? Is the current ordering of y what you want to base your rule on?

Comment: So for example, starting with the first row, y = 800, and I'd want to remove any rows where y=700:900. That would drop rows 2, 3, and 5.

Comment: x isn't relevant to this function, it's just metadata that will be polled elsewhere. And the order of Y is irrelevant and can be sorted, I just want to remove any values that are +/- 100.

Comment: Remove any rows? Or only adjacent? If any then this is weird, from the fist row you will drop all y in the range 700-900, from the second row all y in the range 750-950, and so on until you have nothing left? In this case order is important.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. I think for my purposes sorting y numerically and then iterating the +/- drop would work.



I'm working on sales data, we get an order of item X and income of value Y. Upstream the data is provided as a histogram + list of bins. I'm trying to identify peaks in income value. I have a peak in income value at 800 and 850, but all I need to know is we have a peak around 800 +/- 100, another peak at 100 +/- 100, etc. 

Due to the upstream process and reporting requirements I can't edit the binsize, and need to work on ouput from the histogram as provided.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question. If you expect to identify a series of peaks, then that may involve something else than filtering rows. think about what you really expect as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
library(dplyr)

input %>% 
  filter(!(y >= first(y) - 100 & y <= first(y) + 100) | y== first(y))
```

```
    x   y
1 100 800
2 300 100
3 200 901
4 200 699
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you, I can definitely work around that with a loop.